# Problem in PHP when joining tables having columns with the same name

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have joined two tables which both have a column named 'Name'. In PHP I am writing a script that retrieve the values of the columns and store it in variables:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$table1name = $row['Name'];   
$table2Name = $row['Name'];
```

Of course the variables will not give the values of the 2 columns, but they will both give the same value from the column of the second table. Is there a way, without changing the name of the columns in the database, to retrieve the distinct values of both columns?

Comment: Note, although you should alias similar names, this has more do with PHP's `mysql_fetch_array()` than MySQL.

Comment: This is an SQL issue (which is solved by using aliases), not a PHP problem...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use alias in mysql

```
SELECT table1.name AS name1
```

Answer (score 8):

yes. in your SQL query use the `AS` keyword to specify the desired alias.

Example:

```
SELECT `tbl_1`.`field` AS `tbl_1_field`, `tbl_2`.`field` AS `tbl_2_field` FROM....
```

back ticks are not required, that is just how I learned SQL

Comment: `AS` isn't required to define an alias, but it does make it more obvious

Comment: The keyword AS is also optional, at least in MySQL.

Comment: @yes123: it only gets worse, the higher your rep gets.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference them in your mysql query with table qualifiers, eg tablea.id, and tableb.id, if you need both IDs in the results, you can do select tablea.id as id1, tableb.id as id2 etc.

Comment: Table aliasing will not solve the issue, only column aliasing will

Comment: I didnt say table aliases, I showed how to alias specific fields. I mentioned table qualifiers to reference them to then alias them